# Python Decorator validation

Tags: python, validation

I'm using decorators to validate parameters arriving to my function (via a dictionary object), when I have 2 keys or more it works fine. But if I have only key it returns an error (check_person). I defined 2 functions to exemplify my problem:

```
    def required(**mandatory):
        """

        :param mandatory:
        :return:
        """

        def decorator(f):
            @wraps(f)
            def wrapper(**dicts):
                for argname, d in dicts.items():
                    for key in mandatory.get(argname, []):
                        if key not in d:
                            raise Exception('Key "%s" is missing from argument "%s"' % (key, argname))
                return f(**dicts)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

@required(json_request=(_PROVIDER, _REPORT))
def check_campaign(json_request):
    """

    :param json_request:
    :return:
    """

    return True

@required(json_request=(_NAME))
def check_person(json_request=None):
    """

    :param json_request:
    :return:
    """
    return True
```

I need to change check_person to:

```
if _NAME in json_request:
        return True
    return False
```

To make it work.

When I try:

```
self.assertTrue(validator.check_person(json_request=json.loads("""{"name": "Elon Musk"}""")))
```

or specifically:

```
{"name": "Elon Musk"}
```

I get:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzo/utils/validate/validator_test.py", line 46, in test_person
    self.assertTrue(validator.check_person(json_request=json.loads("""{"name": "Elon Musk"}""")))
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzo/utils/validate/validator.py", line 26, in wrapper
    raise Exception('Key "%s" is missing from argument "%s"' % (key, argname))
Exception: Key "n" is missing from argument "json_request"
```

When my dictionary has more than 1 key it works fine (Like check_campaign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a subtle syntax distinction.

With `@required(json_request=(_PROVIDER, _REPORT))`, your request is a tuple: (_PROVIDER, _REPORT).

By contrast, in your failing example `@required(json_request=(_NAME))`, the request is only the value `_NAME`. To make it a tuple, add a comma: `@required(json_request=(_NAME,))`. That ought to fix all your troubles.

---

As to why you get that *exact* error, you iterate over the argument. When it's a tuple, it works as you want. When it's a string, iterating over it gets you each letter. That's why `'n'` was missing: it's  the first letter of `'name'`.